# Adding a total column PIVOT TABLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table, sql-server-2014

Here is my code guys i want to be able to return an total column of 2016,2015,2014,2013 but when i do this

`Sum([2016]+[2015]+[2014]+[2013])` as Revenue like this its returns NULLS.

or this 
`Sum(2016+2015+2014+2013)` as Revenue like this returns a different number than if you go take a calculator and add the numbers in 2013 2014 2015 and 2016 
The numbers doesn't add up in the total column.

```
 SELECT        AirCarrierName, 
        SUM([2016]) AS [2016], 
        SUM([2015]) AS [2015], 
        SUM([2014]) AS [2014], 
        SUM([2013]) AS [2013]

        FROM            Sum_Orders 


        PIVOT
        (
         SUM(Sum_Orders.Sum_SellPrice)
                FOR Sum_Orders.OrderperiodYear IN ([2016],[2015],[2014],[2013])
            )AS pvt 

            WHERE OrderStatus IN ('INVOICED','OPEN') AND AirCarrierName 
    NOT LIKE 'NULL' 
    and AirCarrierName = 'CATHAY PACIFIC AIRWAYS LTD.'

            GROUP BY AirCarrierName


            Order by [2016] desc
```

this code returns the following 
[image]

when i add up the lines for creating the total column this is what i get,
instead of having a nice sum of 2013 to 2016 in total column

```
Sum([2016]+[2015]+[2014]+[2013]) as total
```

[image]

this is the query with the total column included which is returning Nulls

```
SELECT        AirCarrierName, 
SUM(Sum_BuyPrice) AS Buy_price, 
SUM(Sum_SellerMargin) AS Margin, sum(Sum_GrossWeightkg/1000)as Kilos_total,
                    SUM([2016]) AS [2016], 
SUM([2015]) AS [2015], SUM([2014]) AS [2014], SUM([2013]) 
                         AS [2013],

                    SUM([2016]+[2015]+[2014]+[2013])as [total]

FROM            Sum_Orders 


PIVOT
(
 SUM(Sum_Orders.Sum_SellPrice)
        FOR Sum_Orders.OrderperiodYear IN ([2016],[2015],[2014],[2013])
    )AS pvt 

    WHERE OrderStatus IN ('INVOICED','OPEN') AND AirCarrierName NOT LIKE 'NULL'

    GROUP BY AirCarrierName
```

Comment: Do you actually store the string literal 'NULL' instead of an actual NULL? And honestly the NOT LIKE is totally pointless because you also specify exactly what the AirCarrierName needs to be.

Comment: If you want some real help you need to provide some real details. Just saying that the totals don't match up is NOT helping us understand the problem. Take a look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange I left the and AirCarrierName = 'CATHAY PACIFIC AIRWAYS LTD.' just to make the results smaller for the example here, i actually dont use that, thats why i have 'not like null ' there that part is not the problem, let me provide more details as per the post that you suggested.

Comment: OK gotcha. But do you really store the string literal 'NULL' instead of NULL?

Comment: yeah, its because when they entered the data, they actually wrote the word "null" instead of leaving it blank, that's why i need ' ' @SeanLange

Comment: This would be a good indication that you need some normalization around that. Why are users typing the carrier name for an order? Shouldn't they be choosing one from a drop down list or something along those lines? That way you control the values.

Comment: I think there actually is the users choose the field 'Null' for non existing, rather than leaving it blank, we need to fix that in the near future,I just update the post, added some details. @SeanLange

Comment: Please post your query that includes the "Total" column, so we can see where you added it to your existing query.   The one that returns NULL for total.

Comment: i just added the code. @TabAlleman